# transpose array in my sheet

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

I'm pushing some data in a spreadsheet from a FB api call with the following line of code :

```
ass = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
ass.getRange('a1').offset(0, 0, ar.length, ar[0].length).setValues(ar);
```

however with this, my data are ordered on two column like this :

```
Data1    Value1
Data2    Value2
Data3    Value3
```

I would like the following output:

```
Data1   Data2   Data3
Value1  Value2  Value3
```

When I'm using the apprendRow method I have an error. I've also tried to refactor my code like this :

```
for (var i in data.data){
    for (var k in data.data[i].values) {
        sheet.appendRow([data.data[i].values[k].value]);
    }
```

But still not successful.

I know that's a commun issue, but I can't find an answers that could help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is only 2 columns you can try this:

```
function transpose(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
  var array = sheet.getRange('A1:B3').getValues();  //or define your own range

  var newArray = array[0].map(function(col, i) { 
    return array.map(function(row) { 
      return row[i] 
    })
  })

  var i = 0;
  while (i < newArray.length) {
    sheet.appendRow(newArray[i]);  // or pick a different sheet to appended to
    i++
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I've come up with the following solution :

```
ass = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
ass.getRange('a1').offset(0, 0, ar.length, ar[0].length).setValues(ar);

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1];
  var DailyReach = sheet.getRange('Sheet1!A1').getValue();
  var WeeklyReach = sheet.getRange('Sheet1!A2').getValue();
  var MonthlyReach = sheet.getRange('Sheet1!A3').getValue();
  sheet.appendRow([DailyReach,WeeklyReach,MonthlyReach]);
```

I'm writing the data into a second sheet. If someone have something better !